# This project uses Play 2.1.2! -- it is like an error but it compiles

Tags: scala, sbt, playframework-2.1, playframework-2.2

I have a Play Framework app and here is a file `project/plugins.sbt`

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.2")
```

When I say `play` I get the following output:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/me/.sbt/plugins
[info] Updating {file:/home/me/.sbt/plugins/}default-c82e21...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_10_0;0.12.2 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /home/me/project123/project

This project uses Play 2.1.2!
Update the Play sbt-plugin version to 2.1.0 (usually in project/plugins.sbt)

[info] Set current project to project123 (in build file:/home/me/project123/)
       _            _
 _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
| '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
|  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
|_|            |__/

play! 2.1.2 (using Java 1.7.0_25 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[project123] $
```

What do I do about him saying

```
This project uses Play 2.1.2!
    Update the Play sbt-plugin version to 2.1.0 (usually in project/plugins.sbt)
```

?

I already did `gen-idea` and `compile` but nothing changes.

Comment: I think the error message is wrong. Maybe you need to download play 2.1.2 and use that?

Comment: Where it is written it's an error?

Comment: @pedrofurla, it's the red color.

Answer (score 2):

The message gives you a clear answer, but it may be hard to understand if you haven't encountered it before.

The message is suggesting that you should change your sbt-plugin version to 2.1.0. The final line of your plugins.sbt file should be replaced with the below line.

`addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")`

Comment: alright. I'm curious, in case I want to use a different play version, where do I specify it?

Comment: This is based on the version of Play that is installed on your machine. If you want to use a different version, you need to download and unzip the version of Play. At that point, you have the option of calling the Play command that is in the bin of the unzipped package or updating the PATH environment variable to use the new Play version.

Comment: well, what you suggested (`addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.0")` doesn't work, now it says `play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.7.0_25 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org` as the welcome message.

Comment: whereas previously it said `play! 2.1.2 (using Java 1.7.0_25 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org`

Comment: Is the message `Update the Play sbt-plugin version ...` still there? I thought that was the thing you were trying to resolve.

Comment: The portion of the log that you pasted in these comments will always be present. From reading your comment on the question, it looks like you think it's an error because it is in red. I'm pretty sure it's red to make it stick out, not to indicate that it is an error.

Comment: your saying that I have to download play 2.12 and call it with a special command line is incorrect, isn't it? because I only changed sbt plugin to be 2.1.2 and instantly play 2.12 starts being used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38997/discussion-between-andrew-jones-and-grienders)